# How can I fade in and then fade out text inside a <div>

Tags: angularjs

My Web page has the following tag:

```
<div data-ng-model="modal.data.message"></div>
```

Is there a simple way using that I can make a message "autosaving" fade into view in the `<div>` and then fade out a couple of seconds after the function returns.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add the `ngShow` directive to your div:

```
<div ng-model="message" ng-show="showMessage" class="message fadein fadeout">{{message}}</div>
```

When saving begins set `showMessage = true` and the message you want to display. When saving is done set `showMessage = false`. To show the message a while longer after the saving is done you can use `$timeout`:

```
// Loadind done here - Show message for 3 more seconds.
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.showMessage = false;
}, 3000);
```

The animation part depends on what version of AngularJS you are using.

Here is an example using 1.2: http://plnkr.co/edit/jBukeP?p=preview

Comment: For sake of completeness, you should include the definition of your CSS classes in the answer as well.